# Electron react app hot reloading from src folder not working

Tags: reactjs, electron, hot-reload

I'm trying to use the hot reload feature in development mode of a react electron app.

It use to work well but I'm having issues with the latest electron version 15+.

I am able to run the app from the build folder but anytime I want to make a change I need to run the build command therefor the hot reloading is not working.

I have change the package.json path to use the public folder. But I get a blank page. however if I make a change to the main.js folder, the app reload but not when I make a change within the src folder of the app itself.

In my package.json if I use the public folder the app is not loading. It only loads when I use the build folder.

```
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "main": "build/main.js",
  "homepage": "./",

 "files": [
      "public/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ],

 "scripts": {
    "electron-dev": "set ELECTRON_START_URL=http://localhost:3000  && electron . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win --arch=x64 --icon=icons/icon.png --prune=true --out=build",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dist": "electron-builder --win"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "15.3.0",
    "electron-builder": "^22.13.1",
    "electron-reload": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "electron-reloader": "^1.2.3"
  }
```

In my public/main.js file;

```
  require('electron-reloader')(module,
    {
      debug: true,
      watchRenderer: true
  });

const startUrl =  url.format({
  pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
  protocol: 'file:',
  slashes: true
});
```

I can also see the watcher in the console;

```
Watched paths: {
  '..': [
    'public'
  ],
  '.': [
    'assets',
    'favicon.ico',
    'icon.png',
    'index.html',
    'logo-black.png',
    'logo.png',
    'logo.svg',
    'main.js',
    'manifest.json',
    'package.json',
    'preload.js',
    'robots.txt'
  ],
  assets: [...]
```

It seams like the public folder is not being watched at all. When ever I make a change to my app inside the src folder. nothing get's picked up. The src folder is not being watched/

What should I look for?

Please comment if you would like to see more code.

[UPDATE]

The start url is not getting picked up in the .env nor in the inline command.

As a temporary solution I am running the build & electron.
Very counter productive!

Answer (score 1):

One potential hacky solution you could use is just using nodemon, and make it re-launch electron each time you change any content inside the src directory. In order to do this you would have to run `npm install --save-dev nodemon`. Then in your packages.json put in the following

```
"dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon --watch ./src/**/* --watch . --exec 'npm run electron'"
```

With respect to the actual question, why are you using electron-reloader over just using electron-reload. It is easy to setup, just by adding the following to your code

```js
require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
  electron: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron'),
  hardResetMethod: 'exit'
});
```